# How to assign a specific button in excel sheet to do some specific task?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I would like to have a button on this excel sheet whose name should be “Save as PDF”.

When I press this button it should save the excel sheet’s all data into PDF at the path- M:\formats\ ‘File Name’

‘File Name’ should be the value of cell No H8.

In another words when I click “Save as PDF” button it should save the excel file in pdf form, into the above mentioned path and also with the name whichever is written in cell no H8.

For example, if the name ANDREW PITTERSON is written in H8 cell then it should save with the same name I.e. ANDREW PITTERSON.

Kindly look at this snapshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQxsT.jpg
THANKS

Comment: This topic has been covered amply and in number of posts. Please do some search on this site for your issue. However following lines may help you.        ~ fPath = "M:\formats\"
    fName = Range("H8").Value
    If InStr(fName, ".") > 0 Then fName = fPath & Range("H8").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, fName & ".pdf", _
                                   xlQualityStandard, , , , , True~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to a great simple article, to do this sort of thing.  http://www.contextures.com/excelvbapdf.html

I've tested the code example in Excel 2013 and it works fine.  The code asks the user what directory to save the PDF in.

But your question says that you also want to save to a specific location (without user intervention) and to get the filename from a cell.

**Update** - And you'd also like to save the file as an XLSM, once the PDF is created.

The code below does what you're after (all credit to the original author, but my own OCD led me change var names to a format that I like).

I'm guessing the OP would like to know HOW it was done, rather than just have the answer, so I've tried to make the example easy to follow, rather than trying to observe best practice - I'd appreciate not being down-voted for this.

Please note,  you must first open the Excel Code window, got to Tools, then **References** and select 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' then click Ok.  This lets you use many useful functions.

I keep the directory path (hard coded) and the filename separate, so that I can get the 'BaseName' in a clearer way.  Obviously this could be done in less lines, but at the risk of making it harder to follow.

```
Sub ExportAPDF_and_SaveAsXLSM()

    Dim wsThisWorkSheet As Worksheet
    Dim objFileSystemObject As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strBasePath As String

    strBasePath = "M:\formats\"
    strFileName = Range("H8")

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set wsThisWorkSheet = ActiveSheet

    wsThisWorkSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strBasePath & strFileName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox "PDF file has been created."

    ' Now we need to get rid of the .PDF extension.  Many ways to code round this, but here is a built in function.
    strFileName = objFileSystemObject.GetBaseName(strFileName) & ".xlsm"

    wsThisWorkSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strBasePath & strFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

    MsgBox "Workbook now saved in XLSM format."


exitHandler:
        Exit Sub
errHandler:
        MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
        Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```

Just add the button (ActiveX Button) to your worksheet and call this sub from the buttons code window (or just paste the code directly into the Button code window).

Hope that helps.

ADDED:
To save the file as an XLSX (No Macros), then replace the code toward the end of the SUB with:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
strFileName = objFileSystemObject.GetBaseName(strFileName) & ".xlsx"
wsThisWorkSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strBasePath & strFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: Dear EyePeaSea, thanks a lot for your great help...codes suggested by you are working fine...one more help i want from you...i want to save the excel file at the same path with the same file name i.e. the value of h8 cell, but this time i want to save this file with excel format (.xlsm). in another words i want that when i click this button it should simply save the sheet as we use save as command. please help in this regard too..;THANKS A LOT...

Comment: Hi Ramji.  I've updated the original answer with the extra 'Save as XLSM' bit.  If you're happy with the response, please mark the my reply as accepted.  Thanks.

Comment: Dear EyePeaSea, Thanks a lot for your kind help. Dear EyePeaSea when i paste the codes suggested by you in button code window (Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(), it gives compile error-expected end sub and then it automatically selects the uppermost line of the codes which is- Private Sub CommandButton1_Click(). kindly tell me how to solve this problem. Please look at the snapshot- http://i.imgur.com/2orLcqt.png   secondly how to mark your reply as accepted, please tell me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Ramji.  The code I pasted was a 'routine', but you've pasted inside another 'routine' "Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()'.    Just remove the line 'Sub ExportAPDF_and_SaveAsXLSM()'.    Also - just to give you feedback - including a screenshot was a *very* good idea - it makes answering problems much easier. Thank you.

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted by (I think) clicking on the green 'Tick' at the top of my answer in the left hand column.   And IMPORTANT - I'd changed the code to work with my test workbook, so the Paths/Cell did not match your requirement.  Please copy the updated answer (above) into your workbook.  The lines I've updated are: 
        **strBasePath = "M:\formats\"**
           and   **strFileName = Range("H8")**

Comment: Dear EyePeaSea, thanks for your good feedback and help...i removed Sub ExportAPDF_and_SaveAsXLSM() and then try to run code now it again is giving compile error- "user defined type not defined" and then it is automatically selecting this line-     objFileSystemObject As New Scripting.FileSystemObject     when i click ok on this error it automatically puts the yellow arrow on the first line..look at these snapshots....please help me in dealing with this problem...thanks dear..    first image http://i.imgur.com/mUb1obf.png   second image (after clicking ok)  http://i.imgur.com/GrRwChz.png

Comment: Hi Ramji.   You haven't included the reference to the Scripting Runtime (in my original answer).  The instruction is:  *Please note, you must first open the Excel Code window, got to Tools, then Options and select 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' then click Ok. This lets you use many useful functions.*  Regards,  Ian

Comment: Ramji,  Typo.  It's  "Tools", then "References" and then select "Microsoft Scripting Runtime'.

Comment: Dear EyePeaSea, there is no 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' in tools menu in options tab. How can i enable it. you can view this snapshot...    http://i.imgur.com/Pl8qzk2.png

Comment: Ramji - My last comment corrected that.  Go to the code editor,  then the Tools Menu,  then **References**.  You'll see a long list.  Scroll down to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime', select it by clicking on it and then clicking OK.

Comment: Thanks EyePeaSea, now it is working fine. One more help i require from you- Could you please tell me that if i want to save the sheet in pdf format at m:\formats\pdf and the excel version of the sheet at m:\formats\excels, then what changes should i make in the codes. currently it is saving both pdf and excel versions of the sheet at the same location which is m:\formats\......please help...

Comment: Hi Ramji, I'm glad it's working. Just add a new line, after MsgBox "PDF file has been created." to change the variable to the new path. For example, add the line strBasePath = "M:\formats\excels\"

Comment: Dear EyePeaSea, i put the line strBasePath = "M:\formats\excels" after MsgBox "PDF file has been created." as you told in the last comment but it is saving the file at the same location. Only this is happening that it is putting the word "excels" then the value of h8 cell in the name of file. for example if the value of h8 is ramji and i run the codes it saves the file at the same location i.e. m:\formats with the name "excelsramji". kindly tell me how to tackle this problem..thanks..

Comment: Please note - the '\' character at the end of the string.  strBasePath = "M:\formats\excels\" - I posted a comment without that, but then deleted the comment and corrected it.  You must be looking at my original comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot EyePeaSea. I am realy grateful to you for your great guidance. now everything is working fine in the sheet. one more thing if you Could please tell me how to save the excel sheet in .xlsx format. by now we are saving the sheet in .xlsm format. i tried to change to codes myself to save it in .xlsx format but could not succeed. please help me in this regard. thanks a lot..

Comment: Hi Ramji.  I've edited my original answer - look toward the end where I say 'Added'.   You need to delete the existing lines - **"strFileName = objFileSystemObject.GetBaseName(strFileName) & ".xlsm"

    wsThisWorkSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strBasePath & strFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled"** and paste in the new 4 lines that I added to my original answer.  IMPORTANT - the saved file will NOT have any VBA code in it - it will be cleaned up.  Also,  if you feel that I've made a big effort to help, you could show your appreciation by clicking on the 'UP' triangle next to my answer

Comment: Dear EyePeaSea, thanks for your new codes. they are working fine. Now a new problem has occurred. when i run the codes it closes the excel sheet in which i have added the codes and opens the file which is saved by the codes. for example i made abc.xlsm excel sheet and added the codes in vb window, now xyz is written in cell no h8 in abc.xlsm excel sheet, now when i will run the codes it closes abc.xlsm and all codes are shown in xyz.xlsx excel sheet. i want it should only save the file in xlsx format it requisite location. it should not close the base file and open the saved file. Please help

Comment: Ramji - this is not a 'problem' - this is the way that Excel works.  If you open an Excel file and then use the menus - File | Save As,  then Excel behaves in the way you describe.  I can't keep adding comments to the original question, which I've answered.  You now want to do something else, and so I suggest that you ask another question, explaining what you need to do.   Also, as I said,  I'd appreciate it if you Upvoted my answer as I've spent a lot of time helping you with your problem.

Comment: Dear EyePeaSea, when i click on the up rectangle right to your answer it shows a massage "Thanks for feedback! once you earn 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score". everytime this massage is shown. i dont know what to do.. thanks..

Comment: Hi Ramji, thank you for trying.  I'm new to posting on StackOverflow and hadn't realised that you can't upvote.  That's ok, don't worry.  I was just hoping to get 1 more point as it means I reach the 50 milestone!   Anyway, hope that was all some help.  Happy to look into your extra requirement if you post it as a new question.  I'd suggest you add your existing code into the question as that makes it easier for me and others to help.  Regards,  Ian.

Comment: thanks you so much EyePeaSea. Really you are the master of vba coding. I always be thankful to you. I am new to vba coding, however i work a lot on excel. Anyway, i am going to ask a new question. I hope you will help me. Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: I Ramji - not a master at VBA.  There are lots of very, very good people on this website and everyone is willing to help.  Good luck.  Regards,  Ian.